# How to send to controller only checked rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid

I have mvc grid like this.

```
@(Html.Grid(Model)
    .Build(col => {
        col.Add(model => Html.CheckBox("Person_" + model.Id));
        col.Add(c => c.Code).Titled(BusinessUI.Code).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).Encoded(false);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Empty(CommonUI.NoInfo)
    .Css("table-bordered table-hover")
)
```

I need send to controller only checked rows when i press submit button. How to do it ?

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete question? Show your views and controller action methods for getting and posting. Thanks.

Comment: I think Html.grid is used to view data not edit so why you want to get its values?

Comment: @Wheels73 i have a controller that loads a list to this view. and i need that when i press submit, i can update checked rows. but i do not know how to select only checked rows, not all

Comment: You need to bind the checkboxes to your model using CheckBoxFor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **bool checked** property in your model, and then on sumbit you are goin to check if that row is checked or not.